# Corruption in the network stack

Tags: tcp, windows-vista, wireshark, corrupt

What could cause WireShark to show (example) 'xxxxxxxxxxx' on the sending machine, and then show 'xxxxxxxxxii' on the receiving machine?  Note that it's not WireShark showing wrong data, the data is actually corrupted when it arrives, causing our TCP/IP protocol to get out of sync.

This is not the real data sent, but this is the pattern of what is happening.  First some bytes that is equal on both sides, and then some bytes that doesn't match on the receiving side (seems to always be 11 bytes but I dont have enough data for real statistics).

It is not terribly hard to reproduce, but on the other hand it doesn't happen all the time either.

The sending side is C# on Vista and the receiver is Windows XP or Windows Server 2003, using C++ and Windows sockets.  But since we check the data with WireShark I *suppose* that shouldn't matter...

Comment: intersting... tcp/ip has data integrity checks and retransmissions and whatnot.... so this hardly seems possible

Comment: You don't inform on what protocol level that you are analyzing the data - more specific information on how you inspect your data, and what the actual data is (examples), may produce clues to what goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen that before where it was solved by replacing the router.

Comment: I've launched wiresarhk to see whether such errors occurs on my own machine at work. I've filetered on Tcp"s "Good checksum" and "Bad checksum" fields/ Curiously, there are many! Maybe 10 or 20 in one minute. How could hardware/router may introduce such errors ?? I could expect error in cable for instance, or in connectivity point (I mean the hole in your network card where you plug the cable).

Comment: I agree with Lars: it's probably a router issue.

Answer (score 0):

As Wireshark name suggests, it shows data transferred over wire. Whatever you are sending and receiving will be shown as-it-is.

Check for protocol stake implementation details like:

1. IPV6 issue
2. What kind of data-link protocol is running
3. Are you using any specialized NIC, some of them do checksum offloading( [here](http://www.cs.duke.edu/ari/trapeze/freenix/node7.html) )
4. What exactly corruption look like? Which specific byte its appearing? Is it in TCP header/ IP header?